# Losses of NAN, Accuracy of 0, I tried everything! (CNN)

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, nan

I'm trying to create a NN which can recognize the letters of the alphabet (26 classes). I apologize for the lengthy post, but I've included all my relevant code to be as clear as possible. In the end I've explained the issue.

The following block is where I name the paths correctly, and standardize/normalize the image and get it ready for training.

```
X = [] # Image data
y = [] # Labels

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(samplewise_center=True)

for path in imagepaths:
  img = cv2.imread(path)
  img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) 
  img = cv2.resize(img, (200, 200))
  img = image.img_to_array(img)
  img = datagen.standardize(img)
  X.append(img)

  # Processing label in image path
  category = path.split("\\")[1]
  #print(category)
  split = (category.split("_"))     
  if int(split[0]) == 0:
    label = int(split[1])
  else:
    label = int(split[0])
  y.append(label)

# Turn X and y into np.array to speed up train_test_split
X = np.array(X, dtype="uint8")
X = X.reshape(len(imagepaths), 200, 200, 1) 
y = np.array(y)
```

Creating the test set.

```
ts = 0.3 
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=ts, random_state=42)
```

Creating a model. Dense of 26, one output for each letter, and size 200,200,1 to match input:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(200, 200, 1))) 
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu')) 
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(26, activation='softmax'))
```

Model compiler and fit:

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy']) 
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=1, batch_size=64, verbose=1, validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
```

The issue comes here where the output of my model.fit is:

```
Train on 54600 samples, validate on 23400 samples
Epoch 1/1
54600/54600 [==============================] - 79s 1ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 1.8315e-05 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
```

I understand that it may not be high accuracy or anything from the get-go, but why are the losses nan? I posted elsewhere and I was first told to normalize my data (which I fixed for this post). Then I was told that it was possible that my dataset is corrupt or leaking - this is not the case because when I don't do 26 letters at once, it works perfectly fine. (Meaning I tested the code, using letters A-J, dense = 10, etc) and got a high accuracy of about 95%.

Any help is appreciated, I've been scratching my had at this for hours!

Comment: would it help if you remove ```img = datagen.standardize(img)``` ?

Comment: I was told that part was required because I need to standardize/normalize my data. Before and after adding that part, I still have the same issue though

Comment: I know this might seem stupid, but sometimes when I face this error I use ```to_categorical``` and it works. can you use this ```from sklearn import preprocessing```   ```y = preprocessing.LabelEncoder().fit(y)``` and then split it 70, 30 as you did in your code @JupyterBoi

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion ill give it a shot! So the `to_categorical` is to hot-encode it right? I read about it .. Would that line you said: `y = preprocessing.LabelEncoder().fit(y)` do the to_categorical? or is that separate? Sorry this is my first NN so I'm still learning the ways!

EDIT: I'd like to add though the code worked without doing this when my dataset was only 10 classes (letters A-J). The issue only arises when doing full 26 letters @HozayfaElRifai

Comment: you can use both in your case, it's up to you and both should work fine. Yes, ```to_categorical``` is a function that can be imported from keras. However, you can import ```OneHotEncoder``` and ```LabelEncoder```  from ```sklearn```.

Comment: What is your target variable look like? One hot encoded or label encoded? Can you share the dataset statistics too.